# How can I simplify that code (jquery) (radio button)

Tags: jquery, hide, show, checked

I would like to show only "#HideLgf" when "#LGF_info" is clicked/checked otherwise hide it, how is it possible ?

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#LGF_info').click(function() {
            $('#HideLgf').show(100);
        });

        $('#DDP_info').click(function () {
            $('#HideLgf').hide();
        });

        $('#EXW_info').click(function () {
            $('#HideLgf').hide();
        });


        $('#DDU_info').click(function () {
            $('#HideLgf').hide();
        });


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. But I must admit that I'd probably change a lot more (e.g. use a class instead of `show()/hide()`, less IDs, a proper function, etc.), but as that's all you've provided us with. And using event delegation via `on` removes the often required `domReady` call and allows to reuse the callbacks on e.g. dynamically added content.

```
$(document)
    .on("click", "#DDP_info, #EXW_info, #DDU_info", function(e) {
        $("#HideLgf").hide();
    })
    .on("click", "#LGF_info", function(e) {
        $("#HideLgf").show(100);
    })
;
```

Comment: Pls explain `e.preventDefault();` purpose

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` cancels the current event but doesn't stop propagation. See [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or [MDN](http://mdn.io/event.preventDefault). As I don't know the elements used and this basically never hurts.

Comment: @nietonfir It might hurt! What if it's a submit button and `#HideLgf` is a loading message?

Comment: @RGraham Than it wouldn't stop the submit event anyway (although I'd have to test that). But ofc the usage depends and ymmv, I'll edit the post to reflect OPs question better. ;-)

Comment: @nietonfir It would :) http://jsfiddle.net/M65qP/ - And as OP is talking about a click on a radio button, it would also stop it being selected too

Comment: thanks it works, but I still have one question: I used it to do like that: " if ($('#LGF_info').is(':checked')) { $('#HideLgf').show(); } else { $('#HideLgf').hide(); }" ,why didn't it work , to me it sounds logical "show only if radio button is checked" "...  ?

Comment: @user254197 that should work. You can always check the ouptut in the console. And you can avoid the if statement entirely by using [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide) with that boolean. Best option right know would be to open a new question imho and post the relevant HTML/Javascript there. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [**`multiple selector`**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) here to simplify your code,

```
$('#LGF_info,#DDP_info,#EXW_info,#DDU_info').click(function () {           
   var cache = $('#HideLgf');
   if(this.id == "HideLgf") {
    cache.stop().show(100);
   }
   else {
    cache.hide();
   } 
});
```

Comment: Please explain what you did so that the OP (and future visitors) will understand the syntax.

Comment: I appreciate the ternary more than anyone, but I hate seeing it without an assignment to a variable.

Comment: @RGraham i was in the middle of editing this post. Now see. please toggle your downvote as an upvote. :)

Comment: @Bala, I don't think RGraham's point was for you to introduce an unused variable, but to prefer `if` statements to conditional operators in this situation.

Comment: actually its not working on my place ,nothing happens when I excecute it(no errors in the console) ..